# Start Downloading a File When Page is Loaded

Tags: javascript, click, download

When the page is finished loading, I want it to open a second page in a new tab/window that will start downloading a file. My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>  
<input type="hidden" id="start_download" onclick="parent.window.open('https://googledrive.com/host/xxxxx', '_blank');">
</head>
<body onload="startDownload()">
<script type="text/javascript">

function startDownload() {
     alert('Downloading...');
     document.getElementById('start_download').click();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code is in an iFrame, BTW. When I test it, I know the function is being executed since it displays the alert, but it does not open the tab and start the download as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to a security feature of the browsers that doesn't allow fake clicks to open new windows. The context of the click event is checked and if it is detected to be faked it's action is not fired.
There seems to be a way to do it using a ajax, but you'll have to search around.

Of course, if your aim is just to trigger a file download and don't need a new window, just create a hidden iframe and point its url to the file you want to download at loading time.